# Embedded Linux with ptxdist, coreutils breaks

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gnu-coreutils

My Intention was to update the "df" command included in the coreutils package because i needed it to also show inodes with `>df -i`. This option is not available on the embedded Version right now.

What i did:
I followed the Quickstart Guide (4.2 -> http://www.pengutronix.de/software/ptxdist/appnotes/OSELAS.BSP-Pengutronix-Generic-arm-Quickstart.pdf). I used the latest version of coreutils from the GNU website. Before i did `>ptxdist targetinstall coreutils` , I wrote this to the coreutils.make file in the rule folder:

```
@$(call install_copy, foo, 0, 0, 0755, $(COREUTILS_DIR)/src/df, /usr/bin/df)
```

Then I used the created embedded Linux on my device. At first sight it seemed like it worked out well. I was able to use the new option `>df -i` , but after some time there where ssh connection errors, it asked for username and password where it shouldnt, i wasnt able to access internal falsh and so on. It seems like this package broke something else within the Linux Version.

What could cause these problems? Have i done sth wrong using the coreutils package?

Comment: `I wrote this to the coreutils.make file in the rule folder` Please write the path to what you call the rule folder.

Comment: the path is: myproject/rules/coreutils.make. This file is generated automaticly when using the command: >ptxdist newpackage target

Comment: Try checking if there is a `/usr/local/lib/ptxdist*/rules/coreutils.make`. If there is you might be overwriting it with your new rule and if the line `@$(call install_copy, foo, 0, 0, 0755, $(COREUTILS_DIR)/src/df, /usr/bin/df)` is the only thing you have in your rule, there might by other coreutil executables that aren't installed because of that.

Comment: Yes there is. This could be the problem, will try to install everything within the package and see if it works out.

Comment: Did it fix the issue?
Should I form it as an answer so the question can be sloved?

Comment: Sorry I didnt replay. Yes it did solve the issue! Thank you. Go ahead and form it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of ptxdist/oselas is that if you have a rule in your project directory ( `project-name/rules/coreutils.make`) it will overwrite the default rule that comes with ptxdist ( `/usr/local/lib/ptxdist*/rules/coreutils.make` ).

The default rule contains build and install procedures for additional applications, `df` included. If you overwrite it with a rule that only builds and install `df` all the other coreutil applications won't be built and installed so your system will lack them.